# iTextSharp external stylesheet

Tags: itext

I am converting HTML to PDF using iTextSharp but am having problems with styling.

I am using iTextSharp version 5 and am able to style the tags using the following code:

```
StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.H1, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "16");
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.P, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "10");
```

I then parse the HTML and style sheet using this:

```
List<IElement> objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), styles);
```

My question is can i import an external stylesheet in instead of having to specify each one of the tags individually?

I have found this code on earlier posts:

```
builder.ImportStylesheet(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "CSS\\Stylesheet.css");
```

but i cannot seem to get this to work, is this from an older version of iTextSharp which has been taken out of the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like its using HtmlToPdfBuilder which is not from the makers of iText or iTextSharp but might still work for you.

**[EDIT]**

Dead link removed, used to be http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/tag/itextsharp/

Comment: Link seems to be dead now :(

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/proinfo-web/source/browse/trunk/HtmlToPdfBuilder.2.0.cs